# Searching substring in nested document in array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

### Situation

There is a document like:

```
{
  ttl: [
    {
      lng: 'en',
      txt: 'English text example'
    },
    {
      lng: 'es',
      txt: 'Spanish text example'
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to write a query for searching substring in the field **`txt`** in all documents of this collection.

---

### Problem

I wrote a query:

```
db.collection.find({
  ttl: {
    $elemMatch: {
      txt: {
        $text: {
          $search: data
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

But I found out, that I can't use method **$text** with array.

---

### Question

How can I search a substring in nested document in array? Are there other ways to do it?

### PS

$elemMatch: [Link to the article](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)
$text: [Link to the article](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/)

Comment: Wouldn't that work for you? `db.collection.find({ "ttl.txt": /text/ })`

Comment: try unwinding the array first.. $unwind, though this will probably only work as part of an aggregation

Comment: If it is an actual [`$text`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) search you want then you actually define the "index" on the elements as in `db.collection.createIndex({ "ttl.txt": "text" })` and then just simply search with `$text` as in `db.collection.find({ "$text": { "$search": data } })`. Because that's how that operation works. I think @DiegoZoracKy put it correctly though and you actually want a [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) search.

Comment: Also, [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) is for "multiple conditions" on an array, such as `db.collection.find({ "ttl": { "$elemMatch": { "lng": "en", "txt": new RegExp(data) } } })`. For "single" conditions it is not needed. `db.collection.find({ "ttl.txt": new RegExp(text) })`